# Go dialogflow sdk WebhookResponse doesn't return the correct json

Tags: json, go, sdk, response, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to write a webhook in Go for Dialogflow, I'm using the apiv2 of the official SDK

```
google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/dialogflow/v2
```

But I can't generate a correct response using the official sdk.

What I mean is that following the documentation and the WebhookResponse struct I can't generate the expected json for the response.

This is the piece of code that I'm using:

```
response = dialogflow.WebhookResponse{
        FulfillmentMessages: []*dialogflow.Intent_Message{
            {
                Message: &dialogflow.Intent_Message_Card_{
                    Card: &dialogflow.Intent_Message_Card{
                        Title:    "Title",
                        Subtitle: "Subtitle",
                        ImageUri: "https://example.com/images/example.png",
                        Buttons: []*dialogflow.Intent_Message_Card_Button{
                            {
                                Text:     "Button",
                                Postback: "https://example.com/path/for/end-user/to/follow",
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

This is the json that it generates:

```
{
  "fulfillment_messages": [
    {
      "Message": {
        "Card": {
          "title": "Title",
          "subtitle": "Subtitle",
          "image_uri": "https://example.com/images/example.png",
          "buttons": [
            {
              "text": "Button",
              "postback": "https://example.com/path/for/end-user/to/follow"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But this is the json that I should send back (according to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook#card_response))

```
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "card": {
        "title": "card title",
        "subtitle": "card text",
        "imageUri": "https://example.com/images/example.png",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "text": "button text",
            "postback": "https://example.com/path/for/end-user/to/follow"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So my json doesn't work, because it has the Message that shouldn't be there, and Card with uppercase first letter. I've tried to send the json of the documentation and it works, Dialog Flow responds correctly.

I don't understand how to generate the correct json using the official SDK. Please consider that I'm pretty new using Go Lang. This is my first project.

This is the documentation that I'm using at the moment:
https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/dialogflow/v2?tab=doc#WebhookResponse
As you can see the **FulfillmentMessages** is an array of **Intent_Message**

```
FulfillmentMessages []*Intent_Message
```

And the Intent_Message has to contain Message ([here](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/dialogflow/v2?tab=doc#Intent_Message) the documentation)

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

H2K

**UPDATE:**
if I use log.Println(response) I can see the correct response inside the log

```
fulfillment_messages:{card:{title:"Title"  subtitle:"Subtitle"  image_uri:"https://example.com/images/example.png"  buttons:{text:"Button"  postback:"https://example.com/path/for/end-user/to/follow"}}}
```

It is not a JSON  but the structure is correct, no Message, no Card...

So the problem is when I return it with Gin and the command:

```
c.JSON(200, response)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution!

I need to use the jsonpb marshaler and return it as string with Gin

Here an example:

```
m := jsonpb.Marshaler{}
result, _ := m.MarshalToString(response)
c.String(200, result)
```

I've totally went crazy on it, I hope that it could be helpful for someone else.